# Why do I have two versions of sqlite?

Tags: macos, sqlite, macos-high-sierra

On my iMac (10.13.6, which is as far as it can be upgraded), I typed `sqlite3` and it said I was running version 3.19.3.

So I tried upgrading with `brew upgrade sqlite3` but it said `sqlite3 3.28.0 already installed`. The SQLite site says 3.28.0 is currently the most up to date version.

How come I have two different versions of SQLite? Does Brew install to a different location than the standard OSX version? And if so, how do I either use the upgraded brew version or upgrade the OSX version?

Comment: `which -a sqlite3` says what?

Comment: @deceze /usr/bin/sqlite3

Comment: That's probably not brew's version of it. The brew version does not appear to be in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, **homebrew** installs links for all binaries it installs in `/usr/local/bin`. You can see that by running:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin
```

So, you need to add that directory to your PATH:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

You likely want to do this in your login profile, which is probably `$HOME/.profile` so that it gets set every time you login.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up creating alias command in the .zshrc file like so:

```
alias sqlite=/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin/sqlite3
```

Don't know if that was the best way, though.

Comment: This didn't work for me. However Mark Setchell's answer above did.